# Fixed width Font Awesome in HighCharts tooltip

Tags: highcharts, font-awesome

I am trying to add Font Awesome icons to HighCharts tooltip. The problem I am facing is Font Awesome icons have different sizes, so they appear a little jagged in the tooltip. In pure html, there is an [easy fix](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/fixed-width-icons) for that to make sure all icons have the same width. However I could not figure out how to do that in HighCharts tooltips because I am using the unicode of Font Awesome icons.

This is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vzjkx7br/7/. When you hover, you will see the star is a little bit to the right of the square. I would like to make them aligned, same width. Appreciate any help

```
code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust your tooltip setting to be like this

```
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function () {
          let s = `<div><b>${this.x}</b>`;
          $.each(this.points, function () {
            var name = this.series.name
            var shape
            if(name === 'Sea-Level Pressure') {
                shape = 'fa-square'
            } else {
                shape = 'fa-star'
            }
            s += `<br/><span style="color: ${this.series.color};"><i class="far ${shape} fa-fw"></i>${this.y}</span>`;
          });
          return s += '</div>';
        }
    }
```

if you test this via JSFiddle, don't fotget to set frameworks & extension as jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You can add an empty character to align the elements a bit `&nbsp;`

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4rxwzfqc/

```
        if(name === 'Sea-Level Pressure') {
            shape = '&nbsp;'
        } else {
            shape = ''
        }
```

There are limited possibilities when it comes to adding styles to elements in Highcharts.
Text and labels in Highcharts are provided in HTML, but because HTML is parsed and rendered in SVG, only a subset is supported.

Documentation: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting#html